# Python works fine on command prompt but failed to run from Jenkins and gives error

Tags: jenkins

Python works fine on command prompt but failed to run from Jenkins and gives error

'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 5):

I closed all the command windows and closed the jenkins client.
Then again connected the jenkins client on slave and it worked for me

Comment: Thanks, this problem happened to me, I install something and set the PATH in the system environment variable. It works in the cmd but gets the error when calling it from Jenkins master. After I closing all cmd windows and it works.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue in WINDOWS 10:

To fix that you may try what worked for me:

1. first you have to add the parent directory into the windows environment path:
   from windows start menu search for 'edit the system environment variables' -> 'environment Variables' -> double check the Path -> enter to parent directory of python installation
2. jenkins - > manage jenkins -> Configure System -> Environment variables -> ADD:
   Name: path 
   Value: all your parent folders in 1. above (that can be extracted also using the batch command "echo %path%" - copy and past)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error. Jenkins requires the path of where your Python application has been installed on your system. To get the path, you simply type python.exe in your directory search bar. For me, it's: C:\Users"$myusername"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310"
Then navigate to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables
Then add variable name=path, and path to your python directory (don't include python.exe at the end), apply and save. In case if it's not working, logout and restart Jenkins.